How to display deserialized JSON data in a RecyclerView using Kotlin?
I am currently working on a project that requires a search feature that retrieves JSON data from a website. The app is supposed to display that data using a RecyclerView. However, Android studio refuses to accept my dataset into the recyclerview adapter. My deserialized JSON data is coming in the form of a List and is deserialized using the KotlinX serializer.
@Serializable
data class searchResults(@SerialName("name") val name: String,
                     @SerialName("description") val description: String,
                     @SerialName("website") val website: String )


val query = Query(searchBox.getText().toString())
            val result = index.search(query)    

val searchObject: List<searchResults> = 
            result.hits.deserialize(searchResults.serializer()) 

adapter = resultsAdapter(searchObject)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter

However, the adapter insists on taking the searchResults deserializer data class with it in the space that it would normally take the ViewHolder data class.
class resultsAdapter(var searchObject: List<searchResults>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<resultsAdapter.resultsViewHolder>(){

inner class resultsViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameResult)
    val description: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionResult)
    val website: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.websiteResult)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): resultsViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false)
    return resultsViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {      
    return searchObject.size

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: resultsViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val currentItem = searchObject[position]
    holder.name.text = currentItem.name
    holder.description.text = currentItem.description
    holder.website.text = currentItem.website


    }

}

From reading documentation online I believe the ViewHolder data class is supposed to be initialized in the results Adapter. It should say:
class resultsAdapter(var searchObject: List<ViewHolder>)

instead of:
class resultsAdapter(var searchObject: List<searchResults>)
during the variable initialization, however, whenever I try to implement that change I am thrown an error saying:
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<searchResults> but 
List<ViewHolder> was expected

What is the correct way to do this?

"the adapter insists on taking the searchResults deserializer data class with it in the space that it would normally take the ViewHolder data class." - can you rephrase this for clarity? How does the adapter "insist" on taking the data class, and what is "the space" you're talking about?

The error code is the insistence. This is regarding the initialization of the variable in the Adapter as shown in the code above.

That ... does not clarify ... You just repeated what I told you was unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
